# Is There a Word for This? A Dream Come True

Tags: vocabulary

Suppose you had a dream (something that exists physically) in your childhood. Now after a long time, someone gives you a little replica of that long-lost dream leaving you romantically amazed and pleased. What is that thing called?

It is a dream come true, but what can it be called in a word?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you talk about dreams and physical objects. Do you mean that there was some object the person coveted and were ambitious to own, or that they literally dreamt about it while they were asleep?

Comment: I wouldn’t normally associate the phrase “dream come true” with a physical object or trinket. I think the phrase usually refers to something more abstract, such as landing an ideal job, accomplishing a difficult goal, or fulfilling some long-time wish.

Comment: Spagirl, we are talking about childhood dreams and wants. No ambitions in that era. But things that give us a great feeling and then when we confront them in adulthood we get a sense of satisfaction (nostalgia).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"[Dejavu](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/deja-vu)" is a word that refers to a strange feeling you get when you have already seen / dreamt / experienced something and you see it happening (again / in reality) right in-front of you.

> "A feeling of having already experienced the present situation".

> "The strange feeling that in some way you have already experienced what is happening now"

It can be a pleasant or routine event (as dejavu can also refer to something that is very common or repetitive). Depends on the context and usage with other words accompanying it.